# Lodash _.flatMapDepth to return an array of objects deep level nested

Tags: javascript, lodash

i am trying to get an array from deep level nested structure, i was able to get one level. Even if i pass depth as 4 also i am not able to get.

any help is appreciated

input

```
let a = [{b: [{c: [{d: [{e: "name"}]}]}]}]
```

tried snippet

```
   let output = _.flatMapDepth(a, 'e', 3);
```

getting empty array

i need to get as below, using lodash

```
output = [{e: "name"}]
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: but i checked at 4 also it was giving empty array, i was thinking it starts from 0

Comment: i see: `'e'` is not an `_.identity`: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMapDepth and https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#identity i.e. `function duplicate(n) {
  return [[[n, n]]];
}
 
_.flatMapDepth([1, 2], duplicate, 2);`

Comment: so what should we do on this case, but if i pass _.flatMapDepth(a, 'b'). its returns me array of objects but if i do for 'e' which is four level down which is not working

Comment: Would you like a non lodash solution. Pure JS?

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: Question: can the array also be `let a = [{b: [{c: [{d: [{e: "name"}]}]}]}, {b: [{c: [{d: [{e: "age"}]}]}]}]` and then the output would be something like `[{e: "name"}, {e: "age"}]` ?

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman yes, can someone explain to me why the question is downvoted

Comment: I have editted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57687894/6086226). I hope this will finally help you.

Comment: Have you seen [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57687894/6086226) @DILEEPTHOMAS

Answer (score 1):

better use _().flatMap

```
 let a = [{b: [{c: [{d: [{e: "name"}]}]}]}];
console.log(a);
let output1 = _(a).flatMap('b').flatMap('c').flatMap('d').value();
console.log(output1); // [ { e: 'name' } ]
let output2 = _(a).flatMap('b').flatMap('c').flatMap('d').flatMap('e').value();
console.log(output2); // [ 'name' ]
```

This one goes through the nested objects and resolves them!

Comment: wihtout using index or depth level can i mention the property name

Comment: output is undefined.

Comment: Not very dynamic as well

Answer (score -1):

From the [Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15):

**[_.flatMapDepth](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMapDepth)**

```
// _.flatMapDepth(collection, [iteratee=_.identity], [depth=1])

function duplicate(n) {
  return [[[n, n]]];
}

_.flatMapDepth([1, 2], duplicate, 2);
// => [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

and **[_.identity](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#identity)**

```
// _.identity(value)

var object = { 'a': 1 };

console.log(_.identity(object) === object);
// => true
```

I think this should help.

---

If this does not help. I have written a JavaScript solution to your problem:

```js
let a = [{
    b: [{
        c: [{
            d: [{
                e: "name"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    b: [{
        c: [{
            d: [{
                e: "age"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

function getDeepKeys(arr, key, maxDepth = 8) {
    let res = [];
    let depth = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const obj = arr[i];
        if (typeof obj !== "object" || obj == null) {
            continue;
        }
        for (const k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                const element = obj[k];
                if (k === key) {
                    res.push(obj);
                    // can also be res.push(element)
                    // if you want the contents of obj to be added to the resulting array
                    continue;
                } else if (depth <= maxDepth) {
                    res = getDeepKeys(element, key).concat(res);
                    depth++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

let keys = getDeepKeys(a, "e");
console.log(keys);
```

Be careful, though. If there's an object without the `e` key, you will get an infinite loop error. Therefor I created the `depth` and `maxDepth` variable. You can adjust this value like so: `getDeepKeys(a, "e", 12);` (now the `maxDepth` equals 12 instead of the default value of 10).